# Check if the css class is changed when a Tab is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, semantic-ui

I'm using [Tab from Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/tab.html) for the top of a table. It contains more tabs and I noticed in Developer tools that the selected one contains beside its normal class elements a new element `active`.

This is the code:

```
 const panes = [
      {
        menuItem: (
          <Menu.Item
            className="tab-title"
            key="Reference"
            style={{
              display: 'block',
              background:'url(https://svgshare.com/i/Nnu.svg) left center no-repeat',
              backgroundSize: 'cover',
              minWidth: 292,
              borderColor: 'transparent',
            }}>
            <p>Reference</p>
          </Menu.Item>
        ),
        render: () => <Tab.Pane>{referenceTab}</Tab.Pane>,
      },
      {
        menuItem: (
          <Menu.Item
            className="tab-title"
            key="List"
            style={{
              display: 'block',
              background:'url(https://svgshare.com/i/Nnu.svg) left center no-repeat',
              backgroundSize: 'cover',
              minWidth: 300,
              borderColor: 'transparent',
            }}>
            <p>List</p>
          </Menu.Item>
        ),
        render: () => <Tab.Pane>{listTab}</Tab.Pane>
      },
    ];

    return (
      <Layout>
          <TabContainer panes={panes} />
      </Layout>
    );
```

And in inspect mode, the selected tab has this class: `active item tab-title` while the non-selected one has `item tab-title`.

Is there a way to use this in code? For example I want to change the background url with another one if class contains `active`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Element.classList.contains("active")`.
[MDN for classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). [MDN for contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/contains)

Edit:
Alternatively, you could add css which would look like

```css
.active.tab-title {
   background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: can I use that inside `style={ ... }` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this for setting a css property dynamically.

```
style={{          
  background-color: ${active ? 'red' : 'blue'},         
}}>
```